# How can show a progress bar when mixing sound using FFmpeg in Flutter?

Tags: ffmpeg, progress-bar, flutter

I am mixing two files(a,b) into one output(c) using FFmpeg. As it takes a long time to mixing a file I would like to display a progress bar. Can someone please guide me on how to go about the same?

String fileMixCommand= "-i "+ a +" -stream_loop -1 -i "+ b +" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=0 "+ c;

Comment: @Gyan any idea about that.please give me ans

Answer (score 0):

From FFmpeg flutter documentation:

Enable statistics callback and follow the progress of an ongoing FFmpeg operation.

```dart
 void statisticsCallback(Statistics statistics) {
     print("Statistics: executionId: ${statistics.executionId}, time: ${statistics.time}, size: ${statistics.size}, bitrate: ${statistics.bitrate}, speed: ${statistics.speed}, videoFrameNumber: ${statistics.videoFrameNumber}, videoQuality: ${statistics.videoQuality}, videoFps: ${statistics.videoFps}");
 }
 ...
 _flutterFFmpegConfig.enableStatisticsCallback(this.statisticsCallback);
```